# How to synchronize data from the main document page and the quick access tab in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

There is a main page [image: main page] with the ability to quickly access documents.

Separately, there is a "Documents" page [image: "Documents" page] on which the folder structure is created.

I want the folder structure from the Documents page to also be visible on the main page, but right now it's empty.

I was trying to add a link to an existing "Documents" page in the Documents quick access web app settings.
Thought that the data is synchronized. But it did not help.

Please advise how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the same issue occurs with other SharePoint site collections.

Add Documents web part in Home page.When you create a new folder structure on the "Documents" page, it will be automatically synchronized to the Home page.
[image]

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?
If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If I misunderstand something, please let me know! If there is any other assistance i can provide, please feel free to let me know, i will do our best to help you.